# Why is the number of additions in this standard matrix multiplication algorithm $n^2(n-1)$?

Tags: algorithms

Here's an algorithm that multiplies two $n\times n$ matrices (actually it outputs $A\cdot A$)
[image: Algorithm picture]

The number of additions that are carried out is $n^2(n − 1)$ and the number of multiplications is $n^3$. The number of store-instructions is $n^2(n + 1)$. The number of read-instructions is of similar magnitude.

Why is the number of additions not $n^3$? I also don't see why the number of store-instructions is $n^2(n + 1)$.

Comment: Perhaps the $k=1$ addition of $0 + a_{i1} \cdot a_{1j}$ isn't counted as an addition, giving you $n-1$ additions in the inner most loop. Similarly, the $c_{ij} := 0$ counts as an additional store, giving you $n+1$ stores for each $i,j$.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is written,
there are $n^3$ additions.

This can be reduced to
$n^2(n-1)$ additions
by initializing
$c_{i,j} = a_{i,1}a_{1.j}$
and have $k$ go from
$2$ to $n$.

If I were coding this,
I would use a temporary for
$c_{i,j}$
and store the total
at the end.